# how to convert value of dropdownList (shows time in DateTime Format) into DateTime and save to database

Tags: asp.net, datetime, drop-down-menu

this is my dropDownList with id =  endtime

```
 <asp:DropDownList   style="width:65%" class="form-control1" ID="endtime" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="endtime_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

through this method i am populating time to my dropdownlist

```
    public  void timeDropdown()
    {
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.ParseExact("00:00", "HH:mm", null);
        DateTime EndTime = DateTime.ParseExact("23:55", "HH:mm", null);
        TimeSpan Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 60, 0);
        starttime.Items.Clear();
        endtime.Items.Clear();
        while (StartTime <= EndTime)
        {
            endtime.Items.Add(StartTime.ToShortTimeString());
            StartTime = StartTime.Add(Interval);
        }
       endtime.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    }
```

here i am getting value of dropdownList and convert it to DateTime and then saving in database. But it gives this exception: 
**'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'**. endtime field in database is also of DateTime datatype.

```
  DateTime end_time = Convert.ToDateTime(endtime.SelectedItem.Text);
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IvrDatas endtime values @endtime",conn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtime", end_time);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***DateTime end_time = Convert.ToDateTime(endtime.SelectedItem.Text);***

Exception should be here, because your endtime.selectedItem.Text is Time without Date.

So you have to add Date to this selectedItem

[image]

then convert to time using solution below

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtime", end_time.ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

**OR**

Don't convert to datetime format.

```
String end_time = endtime.SelectedItem.Text;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endtime", end_time);
```

Comment: i dont want to add date. In the timeDropdown method i have used ParseExact just to get time in hrs and minutes. can u plz tell me the way how to restrict database just to add time?

Comment: if you just want to add time, your database column for this should be nvarchar, and pass modify this ==> end_time.ToString("hh:mm:ss")

Comment: i tried ur above suggestion but it gave same exception

Comment: yeah so can u plz tell me how to do that

Comment: endtime field in database is also of DateTime datatype. <<=== if you don't want to store DATE, your datatype should use NVARCHAR

Comment: try it, theres almost 90% of solution.